# Absolute item is not located relative to its container

Tags: html, css, absolute

I have two items in a 'relative' container.

The problem is that the 'absolute' item should be located relative to the container but it is located relative to the second 'static' item.

Example:

```html
       <div style="position:relative">
           <button style="position:absolute;top: 200px">Botton</button>
           <div style="margin-top: 500px">hi</div>
       </div>
```

The div (with 'hi' text) should be located below the button but somehow the button is located 200px below the 'hi' div.

Note: If I will add border to the container it will behave as expected.

Example for the difference where there is a border and where there is not: [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fribroon/4jd3qb8b/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is working as expected, because one is using `position:absolute` the other is using `margin-top`, the second one won't be doing `margin-top` to the sibling because the sibling is out of the flow (using `position:absolute`)

so instead of `margin-top` use `position:absolute`, or use `margin-top` on both children.

#### `position`

```css
div {
  position: relative
}
div > * {
  position: absolute
}
button {
  top: 200px
}
span {
  top: 300px
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>Botton</button>
  <span>hi</span>
</div>
```

#### `margin`

```css
button {
  margin-top: 200px
}
span {
  margin-top: 300px;
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>Botton</button>
  <span>hi</span>
</div>
```

Comment: But as I explained the 'absolute' children is positioned relative to the 'static' sibling (with the 'margin-top') and not relative to the parent. How can you explain the huge difference when I add border to the parent?

Comment: read carefully my answer, `the second one won't be doing margin-top to the sibling because the sibling is out of the flow (using position:absolute)`

Comment: Can you explain the difference when I add a border to the container? You can see here the example: https://jsfiddle.net/fribroon/4jd3qb8b/

Comment: yes I can, when you use `border` it creates the `box-model` to the div - see [here](https://snag.gy/ZTQMhw.jpg), when not assume the text children `height`'s - see [here](https://snag.gy/ZfclUF.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you delete the `200px` from the `<button style="position:absolute; top: 200px>Botton</button>`?

Comment: No! If I delete the 200px the button will be on the 'hi' and not above it